# can FFMPEG output a video in green or blue scale, like grayscale

Tags: ffmpeg

I asked a question on Ask Unix titled: How to play video in retro monochrome

And I was doing a bit of research and I came across the line:
ffmpeg -i input -vf format=gray output

I don't really understand from the manual what:
-v number
Set the logging verbosity level.
Is for, or why it's in the above command but -f fmt (Force format) seems intuitive enough.

But I was wondering if I could pipe for instance an mp4 into ffmpeg, output it in a monochrome colour, then play that with mpv?

Thanks

Comment: There's no "Ask Unix", it's "Unix & Linux". And although not exactly cross-posting which is frown upon here, it's almost there. You could perhaps edit the other question, I don't see the purpose of posting a just slightly different iteration of the same question here as well.

Comment: `-vf` applies "video filter". `format` is the name of the filter, and `gray` is the first parameter of the "format" filter. The title asks about "green or blue scale" which are not well defined. Your bottom question is "I could pipe for instance an mp4 into ffmpeg, output it in a monochrome colour, then play that with mpv?". It may be possible, but not trivial. I suggest you to do some research, ask more clear question and show some examples.

Comment: Maybe it should be Ask Unix / Linux, although some people might prefer Ask Unix + Linux.

Comment: by green or blue, I know there are probably thousands of different shades of blue or green, I just had an arbitrary colour in mind. Ah, I didn't realise that -v wasn't just v and f together. Thanks. Sorry to hear it's not trivial to pipe in an .mp4 and output a monochrome. I'll do a bit more research. Cheers

Comment: This looks like a promising lead: https://int10h.org/blog/2021/01/simulating-crt-monitors-ffmpeg-pt-1-color/